# Transform .jsx string to .js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is there anyway to output converted .jsx to a string, instead of a file?

e.g. something like:

```
function convert(jsx_string, function(js_string) {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Babel programmatically if that's what you are asking. See the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/api/):

```
var result = babel.transform(jxs_string).code;
```

Make sure to pass the [react preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/) to the function or include in your `.babelrc`.

Answer (score 1):

npm install jsx-to-string

Just see above the link then you will definitely understand the concepts of how the jsx convert to js file.